# PHP File Upload filed to open stream

Tags: php, linux

```
function uploadFile() {
            global $attachments;
            while(list($key,$value) = each($_FILES[images][name]))
            {
            if(!empty($value))
            {
            $filename = $value;
            //the Array will be used later to attach the files and then remove them from server ! array_push($attachments, $filename);
            $dir = "/home/blah/Music/$filename";
            chmod("/home/blah/Music",0777);
            $success = copy($_FILES[images][tmp_name][$key], $dir);
            }
            //
            }
            //
            if ($success) {
            echo " Files Uploaded Successfully<BR>";
  //
  }else {
     exit("Sorry the server was unable to upload the files...");
        }
                                //
        }
```

Trying to upload a file and then send it as an attachment along mail using PHP Mailer

Errors :

```
Warning: copy(/home/blah/Music/Aerial_view_of_Yamuna_Expressway.jpeg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/UI/user/joinmeeting.php on line 292
```

**Updated :**

```
blah@my001server:~$  ls -la for /home/blah/Music
ls: cannot access for: No such file or directory
/home/blah/Music:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 blah blah 4096 Jul  4 10:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 67 blah blah 4096 Sep 21 10:18 ..
```

Why my linux system is not permitting to copy the file ?

Comment: Because you don't have permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Check permissions for target folder.
Set 777 and try again

`$ chmod 777 folder`

So as we see now you dont set write permission to Music folder.
Set it manualy from console, not from php script.

Comment: Try [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: How could you advise someone to chmod 777 ? that's like welcoming robbers into your home.

Comment: @Mihai Iorga first you need find a problem, and than solve it

Comment: @user1667633 are you tried set chmod manualy from console or only from script?

Answer (score 0):

Try with move_uploaded_file (http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) instead of copy :

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES[images][tmp_name][$key], $dir);
```

Comment: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpS9gEer' to '/home/blah/Music/Aerial_view_of_Yamuna_Expressway.jpeg'

Comment: Ok so you should check that you have sufficients rights on /tmp/ (chmod it if no) or check if /home/blah/Music/ really exist (mkdir it if no) or even if you have enough space on your disk (clean it !). :)

Comment: @MrSil  include also this one Warning: move_uploaded_file(/home/blah/Music/Aerial_view_of_Yamuna_Expressway.jpeg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/UI/user/joinmeeting.php on line 293    i know it is happning because i don't have write permission but i don't know how to figure it out

Comment: @Fry_95 I have 500 GB disk space and btw it's kind of permission issue

Comment: Same error here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php#77661 and the issue is "incomplete path"

Comment: Or here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php#95084 "missing directory"

Answer (score 0):

Ok your edit is a bit weird.

```
blah@my001server:~$  ls -la for /home/blah/Music
ls: cannot access for: No such file or directory
/home/blah/Music:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 blah blah 4096 Jul  4 10:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 67 blah blah 4096 Sep 21 10:18 ..
```

That command is erroranous since it is actually:

```
blah@my001server:~$  ls -la /home/blah/Music
```

You should be running.

But ok I see a problem. The file `.` which denotes the entire folder has no `www-data` permissions. This means that the default webuser for your Linux distro probably does not have access those files.

Since PHP runs under webuser `www-data` Linux will not permit it to `cp` or `vi` or `gedit` (or anything else for that matter) it anything it is not owning.

You can try:

```
sudo chown /home/blah/Music www-data
```

Instead. This should give some permission to `www-data` to take control of files within the directory.

Of course this raises even bigger problems. Ideally you would want to disconnect any upload dir or anything from your actual web server due to security needs.